# Is there a way to use Scanners in an inner class inside of Java without an exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inner-classes

I have a Top-level public class with an inner class being created in that same class by creating an instance of the top-level class and then creating an instance of the inner class in that instance of the top-level class.

The issue I'm running into is that after I create the Scanner object and try to run the `next()` method, is that the program doesn't allow for the terminal to input anything and then throws an error for there not being a token for it to pick up on.

I have tried using the `hasNext()` method and using try_catch. For me, the intended behavior is that the Scanner object makes the Thread wait for an input from the terminal.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
        int inputValue = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        System.out.printf("%d multiplied by 5 is equal to %d%n%n", inputValue, inputValue*5);

        ScannerTest m = new ScannerTest();
        Scanner2 g = m.new Scanner2();
        g.gG();
    }

    private class Scanner2{

        public void gG(){

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");

            String firstWord = in.next();
            in.close();

            System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord); 
        }
    }
}
```

The exception - `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` - happens when `String firstWord = in.next();` is reached. Again, this code is obviously not going to be very useful normally, but I'm trying to experiment with what's possible.

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+scanner+java.util.NoSuchElementException+No+line+found) before you posted your question? Refer to [ask].

Comment: 'Non-static inner ' is a tautology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Scanner.close()`, as in your line

```
input.close();
```

the `Scanner` will also close the underlying stream from which it is reading. In your case this closes `System.in`. So when you are trying to use a `Scanner` in `g.gG()` to read from `System.in` again there is nothing to read because the stream has already been closed. This is why you are getting this exception.

The correct behaviour would be to close `System.in` when you are done using it, i.e. at the end of the program. However, there is no need to do that since the runtime will close it automatically when the program exits.

PS: on a separate note, if you do want or need to close something you should normally use a `try..finally` or `try-with-resources` statement to ensure that the statement is not skipped in the case of exception which could lead to memory or resource leaks.

Comment: Thank you, just for clarification should I simply ignore the Java(536871799) warning about a potential resource leak when using System.in, or is there a situation where that warning would be important when specifically dealing System.in? Thanks, again, your answer was very concise and helpful for me.

Comment: The `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err` streams are managed automatically, you don't need to open or close them. In this regard, you can safely ignore the warning, or if you still want to close it, just use one `Scanner` and share it between both classes.